# My old HD is corrupted. Can I install windows 10 in it?

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-10, hard-drive, windows-installation

My HD is now corrupted and I can't even boot Windows, don't know about the rest of my data, though. Seems like windows 10 is only free if you previously owned another version of Windows.
I used to have Windows 7, then upgraded to Windows 10. Will the windows 10 installer be able to detect it? What if I need to install it in another HD? How to proceed if it is clean and has no version of windows in it?

Comment: what do the disks SMART stats say about it health?

Comment: @FrankThomasm BIOHD-8 test failed.

Comment: The hard drive is dead. Bin it

Comment: @FrankThomas RIP. But what about my Windows 10 installation? As stated in the question, to my knowledge, Windows 10 is only free if you previously owned another Windows operating system. Will I really have to buy another copy of Windows?

Comment: @PedroChagasIV - Windows 10 will automatically activate on your machine, provided, you don't change the motherboard.  When prompted for a license number, skip that step, you don't need one.

Comment: Your question is a little like someone whose car has defective brakes and steering, but asks whether they should take a ride in it with their kids because otherwise they would need to pay for a taxi.

Answer (score 1):

The harddisk is dead. Toss it away. Your data is lost.

A fresh Windows 10 install on a new hard-disk should work.
I did exactly the same last week on a computer with a dead hard-disk.

Simply install Windows 10 without entering ANY key at all.
It should automatically find the original upgrade Windows 10 key on the Microsoft servers as soon as it is able to get online.

Only replacing the hard-drive should be OK. If you replace the motherboard you will need a new license because too many things have changed.

Comment: To add some more insight into it: https://www.howtogeek.com/226510/how-to-use-your-free-windows-10-license-after-changing-your-pc%E2%80%99s-hardware/

Comment: If the OP can still access data folders on the drive, I would recommend copying that data onto another storage media (flash drive, another hard drive, network-attached storage). 

 (Even if the original drive was viable, the Windows 10 installer will likely try to reformat it to get the OS installed, which would vape the data in the process.)

Comment: @GeorgeErhard HDD needs to be replaced before Windows is installed, your comment in the context of the answer, is confusing